# An statement concerning finite rank projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $T$ be an **isometric operator** on $H$. Suppose that $P$  is a **finite rank projection** with $PT^nP=PT^n$ for every $n\geq1$.

> Q. Can we conclude that $P(H)\subseteq \bigcap_{n\geq1} T^n(H)$

Comment: The equality $T^n(H)=H$ is not valid, unless $T$ is a unitary.

Comment: Note that $PT^nP = PT^n$ is equivalent to $PTP = PT$, i.e., $PT(I-P) = 0$. And the latter just means that $(I-P)H$ is invariant under $T$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take $H=l^2(\mathbb N)$, $T$ right-shift, $P$ projection onto $span(e_1)$, i.e.
$$
Px=(x_1,0,0,\dots).
$$
Then $PT=0$, $e_1\in P(H)$, but $e_1\not\in T^n(H)$ for all $n$. Hence, the inclusion is not even true if intersection is replaced by union.

Comment: Thanks. Seems then we always have $P(H)$ and $\bigcap T^n(H)$ are pairwise orthogonal subspaces! Right?

Comment: In the example, yes.